# How to create JRE bundle using Amazon Corretto in Install4j on a Windows platform

Tags: install4j

I am trialling install4j and am creating an EXE and DMG files for an application with JRE bundled.

We choose to use Amazon Correto 8 so its JRE needs to be bundled.

Here is the link of Amazon Correto 8:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html

I installed install4j on a Windows machine and try to create the bundled JRE for EXE and DMG

There is no problem when creating windows version using https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/8.212.04.2/amazon-corretto-8.212.04.2-windows-x64-jdk.zip

However, When I tried to create it for DMG file using https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/8.212.04.2/amazon-corretto-8.212.04.2-macosx-x64.tar.gz, I encounter the following error.
[error on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86D6U.png)

I also tried to generate it on a Mac but still failed with a different error.[error on mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED9CB.png)

Is there a way I can create the bundled JRE for DMG using Amazon Correto Mac version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create the macOS bundle on a Mac.

The Amazon Corretto JDK on macOS seems to be missing the `release` file. Try copying it from the Windows distribution to the `Contents/Home` folder, then it should continue.